# Unit test for scraping instagram followers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

New on ruby/rails and currently in the process of learning it and writing specs. I've got these two methods for scraping instagram followers

```
def instagram_scraped_followers_count(instagram_username)
        url = "https://www.instagram.com/#{ CGI::escape(instagram_username) }/"
        body = HTTParty.get(url)

        match = body.match(/(?<=content\=")(?<count>\d+[,.]?\d*)(?<unit>[km])?(?=\sFollowers)/) if body
        match['count'].to_f * instagram_multiplier(match['unit']) if match
      end

      def instagram_multiplier(unit)
        case unit
        when 'm' then 1_000_000
        when 'k' then 1_000
        else 1
        end
      end
```

and added unit test for this as below:

```
  context '1,300 followers' do
    let(:html_body) { '<meta content="1,300 Followers, 1,408 Following, 395 Posts' }

    it 'returns 1,300' do
      expect(subject.stats[:instagram]).to eql(1_300.0)
    end
  end
```

My unit test is failing because of this `context '1,300 followers' do` and the error says that `expected: 1300.0  got: 1.0` What did I miss? Is it because there's no condition for it in `instagram_multiplier` method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`match[:count].to_f` of `1,300` return `1`.

I would suggest you change it to `match[:count].gsub(',', '').to_f` where you replace the `,` with nothing then perform a `.to_f`

```
def instagram_scraped_followers_count(instagram_username)
  url = "https://www.instagram.com/#{ CGI::escape(instagram_username) }/"
  body = HTTParty.get(url)

  match = body.match(/(?<=content\=")(?<count>\d+[,.]?\d*)(?<unit>[km])?(?=\sFollowers)/) if body
  match['count'].gsub(',', '').to_f * instagram_multiplier(match['unit']) if match
end

def instagram_multiplier(unit)
  case unit
  when 'm' then 1_000_000
  when 'k' then 1_000
  else 1
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mock HTTP calls, I suggest you use [webmock](https://github.com/bblimke/webmock), a gem tailored for that use case.

It will let you write something along the lines of:

```rb
let(:instagram_username) { 'whatever' }
let(:body) { '...' }

before do
  stub_request(:get, 'https://www.instragram.com/whatever/').and_return(body: body)
end
```

---

## Further considerations

Instagram provides developers with [an API](https://www.instagram.com/developer/). You might want to use this instead of [parsing a HTML document with a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

There might even be a gem that does the Ruby heavy-lifting for you.